# Finding Fourier Coefficients of a Piece-Wise Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I have a piece-wise function:

$f(t) = \begin{Bmatrix}
t & 0 < t < 1\\ 
\frac{(4-t)}{3} & 1 < t < 4
\end{Bmatrix}$

which has period of $4$.

In my attempt to find the coefficients, I found $A_0$ to be $1/2$.

I'm having trouble finding $A_n$. I'm using

$\omega = \frac{\pi }{2}$

as

$\omega = \frac{2\pi }{T}$
 and trying to solve

$$\frac{A_{n}}{2} = \frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{1} t\cdot \cos(n\omega t ) dt + \frac{1}{4}\int_{1}^{4} \frac{4-t}{3} \cdot \cos(n \omega t) dt$$

I keep getting an answer that is different from the solution for $n = 1$,  $A_n =-.270$

[Integral to be solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Igz.gif)

I'm not sure if I am approaching this problem incorrectly, as I have tried solving it using an integral calculator after multiple attempts and I still am getting the wrong answer. Other online resources that I've looked at use a slightly different equation to solve for An, but that is the equation from my textbook.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to surround your equations with dollar signs so the mathjax renders.  People dont want to try to read un-rendered equations.  :)  double-dollar signs for equations displayed in their own line.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

Comment: We cannot help you unless you show us your way to solve that integral.

Comment: I'm getting $-0.135$ on the right-hand side and so $A_1 = 2\cdot (-0.135) = -0.27$. Have you just forgotten to multiply by $2$?

Comment: I found my error. I very stupidly used t instead of (4-t)/3 when solving the integral with bounds 1 - 4. Thank you everyone for helping!